# How to avoid abusive use of REST endpoint

Tags: java, javascript, rest

how can I avoid abusive use of my REST API? For example, I have a website where certain actions earn a bunch of points which are stored within a user account. So technically, when ever this action is performed, I call my REST endpoint to add the points to the user account. The action itself only happens within the website, therefore there is no way to check if the action has really happend from within the backend.

How can I avoid that somebody uses the Javascript debugger to find the call and simply triggers it directly in order to *cheat*... 
Is there some principle to avoid such kind of abusive use?

EDIT: Here is an example to narrow down the question: E.g. we have an waiting queue where you can decrease your waiting period by tweeting about the page. The Twitter SDK has an callback method which fires when the user send the tweet. When this happens, the backend is called, e.g. api.somedomain.net/user/xyz123?hasTweeted=1 or similar.

So my question is, how to protect the last step (call to api.somedomain.net), as somebody could lookup this REST url and trigger the call manually, without creating the tweet.

Comment: Call the Rest endpoint in a js [promise](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) so that you will update the UI on the succes case and otherwise you will be able to show an error message.

Comment: I Assume you do not authenticate user before incrementing the counter? Also the fact that its REST, if you introduce any tricks like token or anything then it would violate the rest principles of being stateless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: Don't use the UI as the definitive state for your users.  Stack Overflow is actually a great example of this.  When I voted up your question, the UI only updated *after* the REST call to the backend completed successfully with no errors.  So you should be waiting for each REST call to finish successfully before updating your state.

In the event that someone tries to "hack" the web page using the JavaScript console, the same logic should apply.  The REST service won't know whence a request is coming, but your logic should prevent malicious use, either intentional or unintentional.

**Edit:**

The solution to your example problem is to have a single REST call for Tweeting about the page which makes the actual REST call to the Twitter *from your server side code*.  The `hasTweeted` count will only get incremented when a complete and successful call to the Twitter API has finished.  This still leaves the door open to malicious users who could blast out Tweets, but Twitter likely has something in place to prevent that.

Comment: But what would be the logic e.g. for a simple counter? When I have a REST endpoint which simply increases the count by one, each time it is called,  triggered by an action which is purely Javascript, I currently see no way of validating it in the scope of the REST service.

Comment: Agree with you partway.  Maybe I'm missing something.  How can OP prevent somebody sniffing the HTTP packet from the UI and resending it?

Comment: Ideally your packets should be encrypted when being sent between the browser and the server.  So even if someone sniffs them, he should not be able to decipher what is contained, or even where a packet begins or ends.

Comment: Hm to be true, its a case which came into my mind while doing something similar but which can be indeed treated by some backend logic. So its more or less theoretical. But I'm thinking of browser games and similar stuff.

Comment: OK we are getting somewhere now.  Please update your OP with an example where you are capturing users clicks (e.g. firing a weapon, etc.) and you are trying to prevent someone from hacking the console.

Comment: I thought of a simple real life example. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

I would not have a API Calls directly from Javascript. If there is a way to abuse it, it most definitely will at some point.

I would try and migrate my front end calls to the backend.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I fear I can not follow yet...

Comment: User clicks in JS, that makes a request to server, and server calls REST API, then server reads response from API, if needed, parses it, and returns response to user, where JS updates interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-generated random keys with limited expiration time.

Send that keys to the browser within data attributes in html and check that they are used only once and remove them after a few time if not used.

EDIT: Simple example in javascript.

```
var keyRing = (function(){
    var maxLifeTime = 900000; // 15 mins.
    var topRing = Math.pow(2,53);
    var keyRing = {
        idx: {},
        ring: [],
        top: 0, 
        bottom: 0,
    };

    function randomId(){
        return String(Math.random()).replace(/^0\./, '');
    };

    return { 
        get: function getKey(){
            var k = randomId(); // Generate new key.
            if (keyRing.idx[k]) return getKey(); // Avoid duplication (Almost impossible)
            var now = (new Date()).getTime();
            var expT = now + maxLifeTime; // Calculate expiration time.

            // Annotate in keyring:
            keyRing.idx[k] = true;
            keyRing.ring[keyRing.top++] = [expT, k];
            keyRing.top = keyRing.top % topRing; // Loop.

            // Discard expired:
            for (
                var i = keyRing.bottom; 
                i != keyRing.top;
                i = ++i % topRing
            ) { 
                if (keyRing.ring[i][0] > now) {
                    keyRing.bottom = i; // Update lower bound.
                    break; // Stop on first unexpired.
                };
                delete(keyRing.idx[keyRing.ring[i][1]]);
                delete(keyRing.ring[i]);
            };

            return k;
        },      
        check: function checkKey(k){
            if (keyRing.idx[k]) {
                delete(keyRing.idx[k]); // Discard.
                return true;
            }; 
            return false;
        },      
    };          
})();       

var k = keyRing.get();
var l = keyRing.get();

console.log (keyRing.check("12489172349")); // False (Hope!)
console.log (keyRing.check(k)); // True
console.log (keyRing.check(k)); // False
console.log (keyRing.check(l)); // True
console.log (keyRing.check(l)); // False
```

Comment: Could you please provide more detail or a link?

Comment: Added simple example in javascript. Hope will help.